# No cargan recursos - Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, servidor, rutas

Buenas. Resulta que tengo un proyecto en Laravel 5.4 el cual ya me funciona correctamente si lo ejecuto tanto en mi equipo como en la red local. El problema surge cuando lo intento ejecutar desde otra red (por ejemplo, desde mi celular) y no cargan los scripts, los css ni las imágenes, aparece así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He investigado y seguí los pasos de [este enlace](https://programacionymas.com/blog/cargar-assets-https-ssl-proyecto-laravel) sin éxito alguno. ¿Cuál puede ser la causa y cómo solucionarlo?

---

Después de revisar, me di cuenta que las rutas de Laravel me están cambiando el nombre de dominio por la IP del servidor, lo cual no está permitiendo cargar los recursos (ejemplo: la ruta aparece como `http://11.11.120.120/Proyecto/public/css/app.css` en lugar de `http://mi.dominio/Proyecto/public/css/app.css`). Ya configuré los archivos .env y config/app.php con el nombre de dominio y me sigue arrojando la ruta con la IP.

Comment: como estas insertando los css y los js ?

Comment: los estoy insertando mediante el helper `asset()`, ubicando los archivos en la carpeta public. Ya verifiqué y ese no es el problema, puesto que los archivos css y js de Laravel tampoco están cargando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por fin encontré la solución. Efectivamente el lío era que Laravel me generaba la ruta con la IP privada y no con el nombre del dominio. Para solucionar esto, agregué al archivo routes/web.php la siguiente línea al inicio del código:

`URL::forceRootUrl('http://mi.dominio/Proyecto/public');`

Ojalá esto le puede servir a alguien.